# Is there any way to get all "properties" of "control view" in desktops application window using Java or any other library?

Tags: java, winapi, desktop-application, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

Is there any way to get all "properties" of a "control view" in a window of desktops application using Java or any other library? I have tried with a java wrapper (www.github.com/mmarquee/ui-automation) for "Microsoft UI Automation" ([https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009(v=vs.85).aspx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE4ht.png)), but couldn't find a way to get all properties (elements) of a desktop window. If you know any better way to do this, please reply with sample codes.
Thanks in advance.[Please refer this link (image) to get what i mean by properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE4ht.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, `Inspect.exe` is what you need. If Windows SDK is installed on your PC, `Inspect.exe` can be found here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\<winver>\bin\x64
```

Source: [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) for pywinauto. Yes, it's Python. Don't know good Java wrappers since I'm not in Java world.

Comment: Thanks @Vasily for your response. Inspect.exe is the correct choice if we find the the elements of a property manually, but I'm looking for find all elements of a window programmatically  (something like getPageSource in selenium for webPages)

Comment: You can use method `.print_control_identifiers()` from Python library [pywinauto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto) or one of these libraries: [UI-Automation-tools](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/wiki/UI-Automation-tools-ratings).